# Jquery ajax response rendered as HTML instead of JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hi I am making a ajax call

```
$(function () {
  $('.pagination a').click(function () {
    $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

I thought that the last argument of $get would ensure that response is rendered as Javascript but it is being processed as HTML. I don't understand why.

My controller index action:

```
  def index
    @accounts = Account.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
```

My in index.js.erb

```
alert("This is an AJAX request.");
```

the log:

```
Started GET "/admin/accounts?page=2&_=1415008178615" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-03 09:50:01 +0000
Processing by Admin::AccountsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "_"=>"1415008178615"}
```

and then ends with

```
  Rendered admin/accounts/_accounts.haml (207.1ms)
  Rendered admin/shared/_content_card.html.haml (210.7ms)
  Rendered admin/accounts/index.haml within layouts/admin (364.1ms)
```

Comment: Provide more info, e.g. what your controller is saying.

Comment: dataType "script" => `"Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. "` And how does your JS looks like?

Comment: I see...so how do I get rails to render js?

Comment: @evoo, I meant not the source, but some more logs (when request comes to server and how does it response).

Comment: Sorry blelump, I have updated my post to include these.

Comment: You're using it for pagination. Does it work first time and then stops or it doesnt work at all? Do you have your js code placed within `document.ready`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to all who tried to answer this question. The problem turned out to be in config/routes.rb

```
namespace :admin, :defaults => { :format => "html" } do
```

this line defaulted all the requests to be processed as HTML and after removing the default, and adding the following code to the index action in the controller, it all works perfectly.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js {render :layout => false }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Jquery ajax response rendered as HTML instead of JS

**This could be due to a number of things. The href of anchor tag is same as the url for ajax request so *i think your js function is not being called at all*** and It's sending an html request because that's what a link does by default. To check if it's calling your js function or not you can use a simple console.log or alert statements inside your js function and check if they are being fired. Also if you are using [`turbolinks`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) then you should try to use jquery [`on function`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Try something like this:

```
$(document).on("click",".pagination a", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
})
```

Edit:

If get function isn't working then try the verbose [`ajax method`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) of jquery

```
$(document).on("click",".pagination a", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "script"
  });
})
```

**OR**

If that doesn't work either then instead of calling ajax method by js just use [`remote`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to) option of link_to and it'll dry up your code as well

```
= link_to "some anchor", some_route_path, remote: true
```

Comment: I have tested the function before posting this and it is being called. I have tested the 'on function' and that did not many any difference.

Comment: @evoo if function is being called then whether you use on or not doesn't really matter. Try the verbose ajax method of jquery or simply use remote option of link_to. Check updated answer for details

Answer (score -1):

Try to change type of dataType(last argument) to JSON

```
$(function () {
  $('.pagination a').click(function () {
    $.get(this.href, null, null, "json");
    return false;
  });
});
```

From here: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
dataType
Type: String
The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html).
```

EDIT: 
This can be error with your RAILS server. You need to explicitly tell rails route to render json. Otherwise it renders html templates.
So, if you cange your backend code to this:

```
def index
    @accounts = Account.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    render json: @acounts
  end
```

the result would be JSON

**EDIT2:**

So, if you are trying to get script, you can try http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
$.getScript(url, successCallback);
```

Comment: That also seems to be processing as HTML.

Comment: I need to render javascript and not json. In this case the controller will always render as json, and I need it to render html first.